# How to move CCSprite Using Accelerometer

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

hi I am developing a cocos2d Game. I want to move `CCSprite` with accelerometer value change. I have implemented this code for accelerometer. but in landscape position tilt iphone sprite is moving up and down. but i want to move sprite forward and backward.

```
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:1/60];

[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];

[self scheduleUpdate];


- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
    { 
        float deceleration = 0.4f;
        float sinsitivity = 6.0f;
        //float maxVelocity = 100;

        // because we are in landscape mode where x is always +90 or -90
        // float acely = acceleration.x;
        float acelx = acceleration.y; 
        movement = movement * deceleration + acelx * sinsitivity;


        float angleRadians = atanf((float)acceleration.y / (float)acceleration.x);
        float angleDegrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadians);
        // float cocosAngle = angleDegrees;

        if(angleDegrees<85 && angleDegrees >-85 )
        {
            _player.rotation =  angleDegrees;
        }

        //NSLog(@" angle = %f",angleDegrees);



        if([ShieldCover visible]==TRUE)
        {
             ShieldCover.rotation= angleDegrees;
        }


        //  CGPoint converted = ccp( (float)acceleration.y, (float)acceleration.x);

        // update the rotation based on the z-rotation
        // the sprite will always be 'standing up'
        //_player.rotation = (float) CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES( atan2f( converted.x, converted.y) + M_PI );

        //  ShieldCover.rotation =(float) CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES( atan2f( converted.x, converted.y) + M_PI );

    }

    - (void)update:(ccTime)delta {


        //assuming that you have a sprite called _fireman with 100 px width

        if ( _player.position.y > 0 && _player.position.y < 320) {
            //_fireman is at neither edge of the screen so move the paddle!
            _player.position = ccp(_player.position.x, _player.position.y + movement);
        }

        if ( _player.position.y < 0 ) {
            //_fireman hit the left edge of the screen, set the left bound position with no movement.
            _player.position = ccp( _player.position.x, 319);
        }

        if ( _player.position.y > 320 ) {
            //_fireman hit the right edge of the screen, set the right bound position with no movement.
            _player.position = ccp(_player.position.x, 1 );
        }

        if ( _player.position.y < 1 && movement > 1 ) {
            //_fireman is at the left edge of the screen and the device is tiled right. Move the _fireman!
            _player.position = ccp(_player.position.x , _player.position.y+ movement);
        }

        if ( _player.position.y > 319 && movement < 0) {
            //_fireman is at the right edge of the screen and the device is tiled left. Move the _fireman!
            _player.position = ccp(_player.position.x , _player.position.y+ movement);
        }

        barracuda.position = ccp(barracuda.position.x,_player.position.y);
        particles.position = ccp(_player.position.x-30, _player.position.y-10);
        parteMagnet.position = ccp(_player.position.x, _player.position.y);


    }
```

Comment: When posting a question like this, it is helpful if you state what you are trying to achieve ("moving a sprite via accelerometer" which you have done), some relevant code (which you have provided) AND also state what doesn't work, in what way it doesn't work and what you have attempted to resolve it. These last items you have not given us. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Try this

-(id) init
{
   if (self == [super init])
   {
     [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:1/60];
     [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];
     [self scheduleUpdate];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{ 
    float deceleration = 0.4f;
    float sinsitivity = 6.0f;
    float acelx = acceleration.y; 
    movement = movement * deceleration + acelx * sinsitivity;

    float angleRadians = atanf((float)acceleration.y / (float)acceleration.x);
    float angleDegrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadians);
    if(angleDegrees<85 && angleDegrees >-85 )
    {
        _player.rotation =  angleDegrees;
    }
    if([ShieldCover visible]==TRUE)
    {
         ShieldCover.rotation= angleDegrees;
    }
}

- (void)update:(ccTime)delta
{
    if ( _player.position.y > 0 && _player.position.y < 320)
    {
        _player.position = ccp(_player.position.x, _player.position.y + movement);
    }
    if ( _player.position.y < 0 )
    {
        _player.position = ccp( _player.position.x, 319);
    }
    if ( _player.position.y > 320 )
    {
        _player.position = ccp(_player.position.x, 1 );
    }
    if ( _player.position.y < 1 && movement > 1 )
    {
        _player.position = ccp(_player.position.x , _player.position.y+ movement);
    }
    if ( _player.position.y > 319 && movement < 0)
    {
        _player.position = ccp(_player.position.x , _player.position.y+ movement);
    }
    barracuda.position = ccp(barracuda.position.x,_player.position.y);
    particles.position = ccp(_player.position.x-30, _player.position.y-10);
    parteMagnet.position = ccp(_player.position.x, _player.position.y);
}
```

Comment: When answering questions like this, please don't just copy in a huge chunk of code with a couple of small changes. It makes it difficult for someone searching for answers to spot what you have changed. Also, it is far better to EXPLAIN what was done wrong and how it should be corrected. This way everyone can learn something to take with them.

Comment: The first solution provided is dependent on Chipmonk which is a 2d physics engine. The accelerometer can be used to move a CCSprite without the need of a physics engine. There are several ways to achieve what you want. This is a great blog with awesome tutorials to get you moving in the right direction. http://www.raywenderlich.com